# Phonegap - How to add collapasible-set in for loop?

Tags: sql, cordova

I'm stuck. How do I add collapsible-set into for loop? I have tried this code below, but it only shows the h3 and p field. The collapsible-set doesn't work. Please help.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {

    var len = results.rows.length;

         var display ="";

         display +="<div data-role='collapsible-set'>";
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
         display +="<div data-role='collapsible'  data-collapsed='true'>";
         display += "<h3>"+ results.rows.item(i).title +"</h3>";
         display += "<p>"+ results.rows.item(i).line1 +"</p>";
         display +="</div>";
    }
         display +="</div>"; 
          document.getElementById("news_DB").innerHTML = display;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each(results.rows,function(index){ 
           var row = results.rows.item(index);

 $('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>'+row['col_name']+'</h3><p>Content</p></div>').appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});
  });

        }
```